# geonames exception - Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder

Tags: exception, noclassdeffounderror, geonames

I am trying to run a piece of software with which I can estabilish if an entity is geographical or not:

```
public boolean isgeo(String e) throws Exception{

    ToponymSearchCriteria searchCriteria = new ToponymSearchCriteria();
    searchCriteria.setNameEquals(e);
    ToponymSearchResult searchResult = WebService.search(searchCriteria);
    entity = (ArrayList) searchResult.getToponyms();
    for (Toponym toponym : searchResult.getToponyms()) {
         System.out.println(toponym.getName()+" "+ toponym.getCountryName());
      }

    if(entity.size()>0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

but when I call this function I have these exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom/input/SAXBuilder
at org.geonames.WebService.connectAndParse(Unknown Source)
at org.geonames.WebService.search(Unknown Source)
at geonames.utility.isgeo(utility.java:35)
at geonames.main.main(main.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The problem is solved:

It is necessary to download the version of jdom that is on geoname website:

http://www.geonames.org/source-code/

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

you need jdom-1.0 jar. do not download any other version because it will not work. add this jar file to your project.